# sorting a fetchrequest on date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, core-data

I have a core data database that is filled up with data coming from a json webservice.
But I have a problem with the date. This date is coming back like a string. So first thing I want to do is to transform this string to a NSDate. The second thing is to transform this NSDate in the right format so that I can add a sort descriptor on date.

This is what I have at the moment for how I store my date in the core data database.

```
 NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate* d = [df dateFromString:[genkInfo objectForKey:CALENDAR_DATE]];

    kalender.date              = d;
```

And how I get my data.

```
- (void)getKalender // attaches an NSFetchRequest to this UITableViewController
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Kalender"];
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]];

    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.genkDatabase.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Kind regards and thank in advance

**EDIT**

When I do the following log. I get for each record the correct date and a null value

```
  NSLog(@"date  = %@",kalender.date);

    2012-10-08 19:17:12.125 RacingGenk[596:c07] date  = 2013-09-02 22:00:00 +0000
    2012-10-08 19:17:12.125 RacingGenk[596:c07] date  = (null)
```

Comment: It is not clear - are you presenting what you have already tried and found not to be working?  If so, in what way? On initial inspection, your code looks fine.  Your `NSSortDescriptor` should work with the `NSDate` object as-is.

Comment: I've edited my code. and it is still not sorting

Comment: "When I log kalender.date I get for each record the correct date and a null value" - What does that mean exactly? `kalender` has only one `date` property. Perhaps you can add the `NSLog()` commands to your code to make clear what is being logged.

Comment: I've edited my code again. Hope this helps.

Comment: So the output is from 2 different objects? One has a valid date and the other not? How is the string from the web service formatted? You should check that `[df dateFromString:...]` does not return `nil`.

Comment: this is how my webservice returns the date "date": "02/08/2012"

Comment: " I get for each record the correct date and a null value" - I do not understand that. There is only one date in each record.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17715/discussion-between-stef-geelen-and-martin-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion, the format used by the date formatter did not match for date format sent by the web service. Using

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"]
```

fixed the problem.